# How to quit the job in short duration without negative impacts

Tags: professionalism, communication, new-job, job-change, job-offer

I have joined a company last month as a consultant in a long term project. But I have been searching for full time opportunities from long time.

Based on my situation, I didn't have the luxury to wait for full time oppurtunities. I have recently given an interview with other firm and most likely I will be getting the full time position.

Most of the time I have spent in the current job is with training and KT sessions. But I am feeling guilty thinking that I wasted the current company's time and money and also wondering how should I convey it to my manager.

Any advice or suggestions how to go about it is appreciated - how can I minimise negative impacts in this situation?

Comment: Polling our opinion of what we would think of your position is not something this SE can help with.  You could revise the question to ask how to minimize the damage to your carreer when leaving this position.

Comment: @Downvoter, I know it might be unethical to do this way but my situation is different. If possible, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In no particular order (I'm numbering for reference only):

1. Give a heads up about why you kept looking and that you found what you were looking for, no later than when it gets too disruptive for them to get the work interrupted.
2. Ask for a full-time position counter-proposal. If you already got figures from the prospective job, ask for a counter-proposal suggesting a figure (but I would suggest against just saying what it was).
3. Suggest a replacement or two. **Get involved** in the process of such replacement, whether it was your indication or not. If the replacement isn't very good, but it's still better than nothing, say so respectfully.
4. Offer to be on call for limited reasonable questions (I'd say no longer than 20 minutes a call, no longer than 1 hour a week) for a limited reasonable time (more than 1 week, less than 2 months).

Comment: One strong argument to leave is if that other position is permanent. As Ekevoo suggests, current company should be given a chance to match it, but that's all.